# PHP update in pdo with OOP and switch case

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I try to update in table with switch case order by id like this

**index.php**

```
<?php $action = (!empty($_REQUEST['action'])) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : "index";
$user = new User();
switch ($action) {
    case "editenewsaction":
        $main_content = "/main_content/Dashboard/edit_new_news";
        require(DIR_VIEWS . 'layouts' . DS . "default.php");
        if (isset($_POST)) {
            $user_id = $_GET['news_id'];
            $user->uid = $user_id;
            $title = trim($_POST['title']);
            $content = trim($_POST['content']);
            $link = $_POST['link'];
            $user->title = $title;
            $user->content = $content;
            $user->link = $link;
            $user->editnews();
            $main_content = "/main_content/Dashboard/mainIndex";
            require(DIR_VIEWS . 'layouts' . DS . "default.php");
        } else {
            $main_content = "main_content/errors/edit_error_msg";
            require(DIR_VIEWS . 'layouts' . DS . "default.php");
        }
        break;
}
?>
```

---

**user.php**

```
require(DIR_MODELS . 'database.php');
$database = new MySQLDatabase();

class User {

    protected static $table_data = "data";
    public $uid;
    public $title;
    public $content;
    public $link;

    public function editnews() {
        global $database;
        $newsid = $this->uid;
        $utitle = $this->title;
        $ucontent = $this->content;
        $ulink = $this->link;
        $sql = $database->connect->prepare("UPDATE " . self::$table_data . " SET title = :title, text = :text,links=:links WHERE id = :id");
        $sql->bindParam(':title', $utitle);
        $sql->bindParam(':links', $ucontent);
        $sql->bindParam(':text', $ulink);
        $sql->bindParam(':id', $newsid);
        $sql->execute();
    }

    public static function showTable() {
        global $database;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_data . " ";
        $stmt = $database->connect->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        echo"<table border=1>";
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href=index.php?action=newsview&news_id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['title'] . " </a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href=index.php?action=newsview&news_id=" . $row['id'] . "><img src='{$row['links']}' /> </a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href=index.php?action=editenewsaction&news_id=" . $row['id'] . "><pre>edit</pre></a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href=index.php?action=newsview&news_id=" . $row['id'] . "><pre>delete</pre></a></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

The issue in the `editnews()` method is that it doesn't work. The `ShowTable()` worked well and the create method also worked well just in the update it doesn't work for me. I hope I didn't make too many errors.

Comment: Try to look for the errors after executing the query: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Check the results of the calls you make to the database. Print the content of `$sql` and try running the query directly in the database to double check that the query is correct.

Comment: You have no error checking at all. Why do you assume all your database functions will work perfectly? Catch errors and you'll have an idea what's going on.

Comment: It is necessary that you need to do a commit to the database when you perform any update or insert operation. I don't see any commit in your code. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)

Comment: I don't think he needs a commit if he's only executing a single statement.

Comment: If you want to see what error is produced you can use the PDOStatement::errorInfo function: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL query:

```
UPDATE ... SET title = :title, text = :text,links=:links WHERE id = :id
```

`TEXT` is a [mysql reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html), use back ticks to escape it.

```
UPDATE ... SET title = :title, `text` = :text,links=:links WHERE id = :id
```

In mysql server it is used to defined a data type for holding large amount of text.